# Upgrade to 17.04 Zesty stuck on Postfix configuration

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, postfix, 17.04

I'm in the process of upgrading from 16.10 to 17.04. The install appears to be stuck here:

[image: screenshot]

There doesn't seem to be any way to interact with the "Terminal" view in this window.  I've already panicked, shut down my computer once, booted it back up, retried a "partial upgrade" and ended up here again.

How do I get past this point and finish installing 17.04 - or, worst case, recovery properly back to 16.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1777535): You can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to give focus to the `<Ok>` option, and *then* you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue.

:facepalm: